# ARC UIViewController not being dealloc-ed when popped from stack

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a navigation-based app and I use MBProgressHud like crazy in my app. I converted to ARC when it came out and I experienced a lot of app crashes and I could not understand why. I began using analyzer tools and saw that my memory consumption was through the roof. I went into all of my view controllers and overloaded their dealloc methods to include a write out to NSLog to tell me if they were being dealloced or not. To my surprise, none of the ViewControllers that used MBProgressHUD were being dealloced.

I am calling MBProgressHUD like this:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Retrieving Signature";
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(getSignature) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, When did you expect them to get deallocated? When you went to a previous view, or simply when you called the pop method?

Comment: When I called the pop method. The problem becomes even greater when you use the poptoviewcontroller method because it can cause all of the viewcontrollers in between the current view controller and the one you are popping to to not be deallocated.

Comment: I do not think that poptoviewcontroller would or should deallocate, mostly for reusability reasons and memory performance. Regardless of that, did you hold other references to that controller?

Comment: No other references to the controller, therefore it must be dealloced when popped from the stack otherwise it sits in memory and is not destroyed until the app is terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When done with MBProgressHUD, you need to clean up HUD by setting the delegate to Nil, removing from superview and finally setting the HUD to nil.

```
HUD.delegate = nil;
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
HUD=nil;
```

Comment: Or give the delegate the `__weak` attribute. The delegate likely holding a strong reference to the dismissed view controller.